# Nginx error: client intended to send too large body

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2

Periodically I get an error:

```
This site can't be reached.
The webpage at https://example.com/document might be temporarily down or it my have moved permanently to are new web address.
```

My site is stored on AWS.
I use rails + nginx + passenger.

Nginx error log:

```
client intended to send too large body: 3729822 bytes, 
client: 172.42.35.54, server: example.com, 
request: "POST /document HTTP/1.1", host: "test.example.com", 
referrer: "https://test.example.com/document/new"
```

app log:

`ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/document")`

After a while, the error disappears. I have doubts that this is due to deployment, but I'm not sure. Could you please tell me, with what it can be related and how to fix such a problem?

Answer (score 63):

For me path of `nginx.conf` was `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`.

In my case I just added `client_max_body_size` in `http block` and it worked for me

```
http {
    ...
    client_max_body_size 20M;
}
```

Make sure to `restart nginx` after changing this config

Comment: can also do `nginx reload` after this change.

Comment: can also set on `server` or `location` level, according to https://nginx.org/r/client_max_body_size

Answer (score 31):

[Default](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#client_max_body_size) Nginx config limits client request body with 1Mb.
You have to increase `client_max_body_size` to allow users to post large documents.
Don't miss with the *context* (http, server, location) of this derictive and don't forget to reload configuration or restart Nginx after that.

Answer (score 7):

I have updated `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`

in my case, I have added `client_max_body_size` in `http block` after `sendfile on;` as below

```
http {
    ...
    sendfile on;
    client_max_body_size 20M;
}
```

---

### it is very important to put `client_max_body_size` after `sendfile on;`

Don't forget to restart nginx as below after updating the nginx.conf

For ubuntu

```
sudo service nginx restart
```

For Centos

```
sudo systemctl restart nginx
```

Answer (score 5):

Add the following 3 commands inside the `server` clause of the `nginx.conf`

```
    sendfile on;
    client_max_body_size 20M;
    client_body_buffer_size 20M;
```

Comment: Syntax: client_max_body_size size;
Default: 
client_max_body_size 1m;
Context: http, server, location
Sets the maximum allowed size of the client request body. If the size in a request exceeds the configured value, the 413 (Request Entity Too Large) error is returned to the client. Please be aware that browsers cannot correctly display this error. Setting size to 0 disables checking of client request body size.

Comment: Syntax: client_body_buffer_size size;                                            
Default: 
client_body_buffer_size 8k|16k;
Context: http, server, location
Sets buffer size for reading client request body. In case the request body is larger than the buffer, the whole body or only its part is written to a temporary file. By default, buffer size is equal to two memory pages. This is 8K on x86, other 32-bit platforms, and x86-64. It is usually 16K on other 64-bit platforms.